# AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings: Unsupported pixel format type in iOS10

Tags: ios, ios10, ios-camera

`self.videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
self.videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable : kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]`

throws

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:] Unsupported pixel format type - use -availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes'`

Okay, so I figured to check the available pixel format types.

`(lldb) po self.videoOutput.availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes
▿ Optional<Array<Any>>
  ▿ some : 3 elements
    - 0 : 875704438
    - 1 : 875704422
    - 2 : 1111970369`

That didn't help much. Luckily in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27839444/1304844), there is a category that prints out the pixelFormat names from NSNumbers.

`(lldb) po (self.videoOutput.availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes[2] as! NSNumber).descriptivePixelFormat()
 Optional<String>
  - some : "kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA"`

Hmm, so I guess 32BGRA is supported after all? So I tried getting values directly from the array of available format types:

`self.videoOutput.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable : self.videoOutput.availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes.first!]`

and

`self.videoOutput.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable : self.videoOutput.availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes.last!]`

and both threw the same exception.

I don't have a second device to test on atm. but I remember using the same code a year ago on iOS9 and a different device.

iOS 10, XCode 8, iPhone SE

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *avCaptureVideoDataOutput;

BOOL supportsFullYUVRange = NO;
BOOL supportsY420 = NO;
    _avCaptureVideoDataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

NSArray *supportedPixelFormats = _avCaptureVideoDataOutput.availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes;

for (NSNumber *currentPixelFormat in supportedPixelFormats){
    if ([currentPixelFormat intValue] == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8Planar)
    {
        supportsY420 = YES;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Support Y420 is %d",supportsY420);


for (NSNumber *currentPixelFormat in supportedPixelFormats){
    if ([currentPixelFormat intValue] == kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)
    {
        supportsFullYUVRange = YES;
    }
}
```

NSLog(@"Support 420f is %d",supportsFullYUVRange);

I met the same problem and I get the result running iOS 10.2 in xcode 8.2 with my iPhone SE and iPhone 7.

```
 Support Y420 is 0
 Support 420f is 1
```

So... it seems that Y420 is no longer available in iOS 10...You should use 420f instead...and it works...kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA works fine, too.

```
 if (supportsFullYUVRange){
    [_avCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];
}else{
    [_avCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey]];

}
```